# SSIS Script task, can it process a full dataset in one go, instead of row by row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We have a scenario where the CRM System is populated with data from SSIS via a script task that calls a CRM web method.

It would be very useful to be able to pass an entire table of data to CRM, rather than the current Row by Row method.

Is it possible to work on an entire dataset in an SSIS Script task or do i have to just live with the Row by agonizing row method to build up a table which i then pass to CRM?

Comment: Prepare the webrequest in memory and send it on PostExecute

Comment: Perhaps you can do this with an object-type variable in SSIS?